# Estimating Water Area for Several Regions in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have been trying to estimate the water area for several regions using the `JRC/GSW1_2/MonthlyHistory`. Here is a sample of the code:

```
//Opening the JRC Water Data
var water_data = ee.ImageCollection("JRC/GSW1_2/MonthlyHistory")
var filtered = water_data.filter(
  ee.Filter.date('2018-01-01', '2018-01-31'))
var water_area = ee.Image(filtered.first())

//Creating Region Variable
var turkeyProvinces = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL_SIMPLIFIED_500m/2015/level1")
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq("ADM0_NAME", "Turkey"));

//Calculating Water Areas
var calculateClassArea = function(feature) {
    var areas = ee.Image.pixelArea().addBands(water_area)
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
      groupField: 1,
      groupName: 'class',
    }),
    geometry: feature.geometry(),
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e10
    })
return areas 
}
var districtAreas = turkeyProvinces.map(calculateClassArea);
```

The problem is that the code estimates the area of the regions instead of the Water areas within the regions. [Link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/87a5440aa2b77dcb7e9f375bcb2b9701) to the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you read and understand the data description. Also, add the image to the map to understand what is happening. You would have seen that there is no data for Turkey for the image you have requested:

```
//Opening the JRC Water Data
var water_data = ee.ImageCollection("JRC/GSW1_2/MonthlyHistory")
var filtered = water_data.filter(
  ee.Filter.date('2018-01-01', '2018-01-31'))
var water_area = ee.Image(filtered.first())

// print and display map
print(water_area)
// 0 = no data (black), 1 = Not water (yellow), 2 = Water (blue)
Map.addLayer(water_area, {palette: ["101010","dcff19","280eff"],max: 2}, 'water map')
```

To estimate only the area of water, change line 13:

```
var areas = water_area.eq(2).selfMask().multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea())
```

Then `reduceRegion()` will only calculate the area of the pixels representing water, if they are present within your `geometry` argument.

Note that in your current export, properties `0` represents the area of no data, `1` of 'not water' and `2` the area of water. So it is not 'wrong' that property returns the area of the feature (thus of no data). By changing line 13, you will only export the water area and you do not need the grouped reducer. [Sample of that code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/0511bf0796cf3a1a3276c350c0c7ff02).

Comment: Dear @Kuik, thank you so much for your response. It is very useful. However, there are some differences between water areas. Here is your code (slightly modified). https://code.earthengine.google.com/6dc407b9348d026ce4f7a43b552f4265 , this shows only  a water estimate for one province (namely Konya), the water area is 1690020. However if I estimate the area using a more simplified code https://code.earthengine.google.com/4e9aef6acc4cc0679c6f3fa0f46ab688, it gives the value of 1192828177. The difference could be related to the .multiply before the ee.Image.pixelArea?

Comment: Yes you are correct, I didn't notice that. Normally, you set pixels which are the class you want to have the area for (e.g water) to 1 and then multiply by the pixel area: [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/f5024cd57ef1e0016b306a470af08eb6). I updated the answer

Comment: thank you for your answer. One last question, as you could see, the code only works for a specific date, I want it to estimate for all the available months. Should I open a new question thread in Stack Exchange? Or would this comment be enough? I could not be sure whether this is a totally new question. Thanks.

Comment: Simple solution to give you an idea: [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/c5ce52def744c07181285bf853801d45)

Comment: Dear Kuik, if I understand correctly, on the 28th line (selectors), the "water" should be "sum" ?

Comment: Probably yes. The reduceRegions() renames the dictionary differently than reduceRegion()